# SwiftUI: how to make network request when value of binding changes?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to update my chart view when I swipe to another page in `PagerView`. When I swipe `currentIndex` changes. But I don't understand how to get notified when `currentIndex` changes.
Here is my code:

```
struct MainView: View {

    let network = Network()

    @State private var currentIndex: Int = 0
    @State private var sources: [Source] = []

    var body: some View {
        return ZStack {
            ...
            VStack {
                Text("Температура")
                    .defaultFont(font: .system(size: 30), weight: .regular)

                PagerView(pagesCount: self.sources.count, currentIndex: self.$currentIndex) {
                    ForEach(self.sources, id: \.self) { t in
                        ...
                    }
                }

                if !sources.isEmpty {
                    ChartView(sourceId: $sources[currentIndex].id)
                } else {
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

`PagerView` binds to `currentIndex` so when I swipe a page `currentIndex` changes. `ChartView` has a method `loadData` and I want to call it when I swipe a page to load new chart depends on `sources[currentIndex].id`. Here is code of ChartView:

```
struct ChartView: View {

    @Binding var sourceId: String {
        didSet {
            loadData()
        }
    }
    @State private var points: [TemperaturePoint] = []

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ChartView.makePath(by: self.points, with: proxy)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
        }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }

    func loadData() {
        network.getPoints(sourceId: sourceId) { response in
            switch response {
            case .result(let array):
                self.points = TemperaturePoint.smooth(points: array.results)

            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So question is how to make network calling when `Binding` variable changes? Or maybe I mistake and need to use another way to code this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bound state is changed only `body` of view with `@Binding` is called, ie. actually only refresh happens, and only of part dependent of bound state, so even .onAppear is not called.

Taking about into account and the fact that entire `ChartView` depends on new identifier, the solution would be to make force refresh view as whole, so .onAppear called again, and loaded new data.

Here is code. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4 (with some simplified replicated version).

```
struct ChartView: View {

    @Binding var sourceId: String   // << just binding
    @State private var points: [TemperaturePoint] = []

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ChartView.makePath(by: self.points, with: proxy)
                .stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 2)
        }
        .id(sourceId)                    // << here !!
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }

    func loadData() {
        network.getPoints(sourceId: sourceId) { response in
            switch response {
            case .result(let array):
                self.points = TemperaturePoint.smooth(points: array.results)

            case .error(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain how to use .id()? Is that a custom property (Dynamic Property)?

Comment: @chudin26, no,  .id is standard View modifier, indicating uniqueness of the view instance, such that if id changed view is rebuild, ie. old one destroyed and new one created and injected into view hierarchy - exactly what is needed in considered scenario.